# Encode to Quoted-Printable in TSQL (or FreeMarker)?

Tags: t-sql, freemarker, quoted-printable

I store the message part of lots of emails in an MsSql database. Before sending an email with the message I need to encode it into Quoted-Printable format. I don't encode it before saving it to db because I want to have the original message. And I don't want to have both the original and the encoded one in the db.

I'm using third-party software for sending mails so my only options to encode the messages is when reading them from the database or to encode them in freemarker.

So, does anyone know how to encode the messages from TSQL or FreeMarker? Preferrably a solution that doesn't involve buying a license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options you have are as follows:

1. select the original email from sql server and then encode it in client application.
2. create an extended stored procedure or function using CLR.
3. create a sql function without using CLR. In this case you will have to implement all the Quoted Printable rules. This solution would be really messy and may not be very efficient also.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about the SQL CLR Integration in SQL Server 2008. I want to call a third-party dll that I couldn't get into the sql server so in the end it seems easier to just store the encoded version in the db as well.